# Datetime parsing throw Format Exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

when I changed the system date format as `dd/mm/yyyy`, the web application throwing the format error, the error attached here,

[image]

if the system have default date format, its working fine. I tried to format the string as well, but its too not worked. Please help me to correct the issue.

EDITED

Here is the code raising the exception

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdon", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(createdon);
```

Comment: Better post code, avoid putting images. BTW `mm` means minutes not months. `MM` is used for months. Use `TryParseExact` instead of parse, because it's culture specific

Comment: Can you please post the line that results in an exception?

Comment: There is no error in the code, there is culture issue, try using `TryParseExact` with specified formatting `dd/MM/yyyy` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx

Comment: how you get createdon? is it from control ?

Comment: Createdon its a value from jquery Datetime picker

Comment: what is the date time format given in jquery Datetime picker?

Comment: its default "mm/dd/yy"

Comment: @Delphian - as wudzik already pointed out, at least in .Net, `mm` and `MM` mean different things. So in .Net terms, the format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

When using `DateTime.Parse()`, if you want it to parse dates using a format other than the culture the program is running under, you need to specify an IFormatProvider as the second argument to specify which incoming date format you are expecting.

Example:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdon", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value
   = DateTime.Parse(createdon, new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
```

This will parse dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, the default format for the US.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can use DateTime.ParseExact if you have a strict format you want to adhere to

Comment: @V4Vendetta, I was using mm in the general understanding, not the .NET-specific format string. But good point, I fixed it.

Comment: I have modified the code as "DateTime.ParseExact(createdon,"d",new CultureInfo("en-US", true));" but now getting the error "Error in Job registration: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by correcting the code as,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@createdon", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(createdon, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

so its working any system Datetime settings, thank you all.